# Which is the preferred mode used in Bluetooth 4.0(smart ready)?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

When two android smartphones with Bluetooth 4.0(smart ready) are connected over bluetooth, will it be connected over BR/EDR or BLE. How to connect them over BLE?
Note: All these using the user application provided by the smartphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though both the device can support Bluetooth low energy(BLE) as well as Bluetooth classic (BR/EDR) i.e. Bluetooth smart ready, at a time it can advertise either in BR/EDR or BLE. And hence the Connection mode will the advertisement mode used.

Since the Android smartphones advertise in BR/EDR mode by default devices will be connected in BR/EDR.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to see BLE and BR/EDR as two completely different things.  So, it's like asking "which is preferred WiFi or Bluetooth?".  They do completely different things.  For example, you can't stream audio over BLE or create something like a serial port (like RFCOMM in BR/EDR).  So most of what you did before with Bluetooth is still done over BR/EDR.